# Get exact memory usage inside python

Tags: python

Let's suppose that I want to know how much the variables on a program is using

```
s1 = "a long string"
s2 = "another long string"
```

I want to know if it possible to know the usage of RAM of both strings, is there a way?

Comment: There are many answers out there if you search for, perhaps, _python memory usage_. Did you do any research? If so please outline in your question why your research led you to create a question here - what aspects of your question weren’t answered by the many resources out there?

Answer (score 0):

I think  `sys.getsizeof` will solve your problem. It will show size of your variable

```
from sys import getsizeof


data = "abcdefghij"
print(getsizeof(data))
```